# How to clean url variable with htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a link like this:
http://localhost/dimi/home?go=post&app=tagline&post_id=222

How do I rewrite the url to look like this:
http://localhost/dimi/home/post/tagline/222

What tried is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home$ home.php [L]
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]+)/?$ home.php?go=$1 [L,NC]
```

I just want to hide the variables for security purposes.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this in dimi directory.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ $1.php?go=$2&app=$3&post_id=$4 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: It worked but I love it when you can explain your answer.please

Comment: We capturing every match from url and putting those caputre groups $1,$2.. to the respective field of original url in that way we are internally rewriting the url to original one, you can accept this as an answer if it helps you. more learning http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html